# (IDA/Windbg) break after run

Tags: ida, windbg

I want to break/debug/stop execution on the first line just after I run/go. So, in other words, I debug a executable with a dialog box and a command button. I wait for the program to load the dialog and then I want to start debugging on the first line of disassembly just after I click the button. Is there a way to do this? Oh, it can be done or IDA or Windbg.
Thanks in advance,
Adi